# Scraping images with corresponding names as seen in the URLs

Tags: web, scrapy, screen-scraping

Basically I have scraped thousands of pictures and managed to place them into folders categorised by name. Within these folders the images are labelled with lots of random numbers. I am wondering if there is a way to extract the label from the Url to name the image.

For example.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/13002044/Affenpinscher-On-White-04.jpg
```

The corresponding picture to this link is labelled  `02563d3fe1d2933fe6dec09dc00b69bbabbf1560.jpg`

and I would like it to be matching the link: `Affenpinscher-On-White-04.jpg`

Does someone know how I can do this?

I have used scrapy for this.

Comment: Could you share your code so we can see how these images are being collected?

Answer (score 1):

If you just look into scrapy documentation, this is already available

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#module-scrapy.pipelines.files

#### Extending the Media Pipelines

> See here the methods that you can override in your custom Files Pipeline:

> classscrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline[source]
> file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None)[source]
> This method is called once per downloaded item. It returns the download path of the file originating from the specified response.

> In addition to response, this method receives the original request, info and item

> You can override this method to customize the download path of each file.

> For example, if file URLs end like regular paths (e.g. https://example.com/a/b/c/foo.png), you can use the following approach to download all files into the files folder with their original filenames (e.g. files/foo.png):

```py
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class MyFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        return 'files/' + os.path.basename(urlparse(request.url).path)
```

> Similarly, you can use the item to determine the file path based on some item property.

> By default the file_path() method returns full/..

> New in version 2.4: The item parameter.